# Валидация форм в Laravel (не возвращается $errors)

Tags: php, laravel

Учу валидацию форм в Laravel, сделал все по документации, но на экране не отображаются ошибки валидации. При правильном вводе валидация срабатывает и dump'ом я получаю массив с введенными данными, а вот ошибки - ни в какую

**Kernel.php**

```
    protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
];
```

**contacts.blade.php**

```
@section('content')
<div class="contacts">

    <h2>Оставьте свое сообщение</h2>

    @if(count($errors) > 0 )
        <h2>Errors:</h2>
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
            <p>{{$error}}</p>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
    @endif

    <form action="{{route('contacts')}}" method="POST">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="text" name="name"  placeholder="Ваше имя"> <br>
    <input type="text" name="email"  placeholder="Ваш email">
    <p>Ваше сообщение</p>
    <textarea rows="10" cols="45" name="text"></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" name="send" value="Отправить">
</form>
</div>
@endsection
```

**ContactsController.php**

```
<?php
```

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ContactsController extends Controller
{
    public function show(Request $request) {

```
    if ($request->isMethod('post')) {

        $rules = [
            'name' => 'required|max:10',
            'email' => 'required|email'
        ];
        $this->validate($request, $rules);
        dump($request->all());
    }

     return view('contacts');
}
```

}

**web.php**

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/contacts', ['uses'=>'ContactsController@show', 'as' => 'contacts']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена
В файле **Kernel.php** забыл убрать

```
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
```

из группы web, как убрал - все заработало